# Read and write a file using Unix or Perl script

Tags: perl, file, unix

I am new in Unix, and I want to write script that reads a file and replaces some words in the file with other words. The operations to replace are not so difficult to make. But how can I read the file's content and "work" on this via a Unix script, and how do I write the results to a new file?

Which commands should I use?

Answer (score 3):

There must be a million and one online tutorials for doing this in any language. Using sed this is trivial:

```
sed 's/foo/replacement/' in.txt > out.txt
```

Or as a perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 's/foo/replacement/g; print' in.txt > out.txt
```

And in a perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $file, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'out.txt' or die $!;

while(<$file>){
    s/foo/replacement/g;
    print $out "$_\n";
}
```

--- in.txt ---

```
foo
bar
baz
one
two
three
```

Comment: Why `chomp` and re-adding `\n` on output?

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl one liner:

```
perl -p -e 's/pattern/replace/g' /path/to/infile > /path/to/outfile
```

You can do an in-place replacement by using `-i` flag:

```
perl -pi -e 's/pattern/replace/g' /path/to/infile
```

Answer (score 1):

In unix you can read from files and write to files from the shell and bash scripts without programming.

e.g.

```
echo "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat" >test.txt
```

will write this text in the *test.txt* file.

```
cat test.txt >test_copy.txt
```

will read the file and write it to *test_copy.txt*

This is not very useful, because **cp** is less typing, but...

You can add little apps in between :

```
cat test.txt | perl -p -e 's/cat/dog/' >corrected_test.txt
```

this will call perl to substitute the wrong animal to the correct one. The **-p** parameter tells perl to execute the command on all input lines and print the result to the output.

With these lego-blocks you can build useful larger apps.

e.g. create a **fix_cat.sh** file (which will be a **bash** script)

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $1 \
  | perl -n -p -e 's/cat/dog/' \
  > $2
```

and do **chmod +x fix_cat.sh**, to make the bash script executable. (The \ at the end of lines means to let the same line continue on the next line, that reads a bit easier and makes it handy to add corrections in between.)

now you can

```
$./fix_cat.sh test.txt new_text.txt
```

and you will get the corrected text in *new_text.txt*

good luck.

Comment: @RobEarl thanks for the -n -p fix. I did not know that -p included -n. One learns everyday.